# Error with clip raster by extend

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, clip

```
2020-03-12T12:15:48     INFO    gdal_translate -projwin 14.780610232572156 37.735515963469275 15.197846199041757 37.43676716072688 -of GTiff cache=PreferNetwork&crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&format=GeoTIFF&identifier=1&url=http://map.sitr.regione.sicilia.it/orbs/services/raster/Slope2x2_ata0708/MapServer/WCSServer /var/folders/ds/sjyv9bzj0zg8rzpsvhbwtygr0000gn/T/processing_167546b6f1684d4a8d89e44283c0ea80/21588c8d69914a859931003cd12f1cdc/OUTPUT.tif
2020-03-12T12:15:48     INFO    GDAL execution console output
             /bin/sh: /var/folders/ds/sjyv9bzj0zg8rzpsvhbwtygr0000gn/T/processing_167546b6f1684d4a8d89e44283c0ea80/21588c8d69914a859931003cd12f1cdc/OUTPUT.tif: No such file or directory

FAILURE: No target dataset specified.
Usage: gdal_translate [--help-general] [--long-usage]
 [-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/
 CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-strict]
 [-of format] [-b band] [-mask band] [-expand {gray|rgb|rgba}]
 [-outsize xsize[%]|0 ysize[%]|0] [-tr xres yres]
 [-r {nearest,bilinear,cubic,cubicspline,lanczos,average,mode}]
 [-unscale] [-scale[_bn] [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]]* [-exponent[_bn] exp_val]*
 [-srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize] [-epo] [-eco]
 [-projwin ulx uly lrx lry] [-projwin_srs srs_def]
 [-a_srs srs_def] [-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry] [-a_nodata value]
 [-a_scale value] [-a_offset value]
 [-gcp pixel line easting northing [elevation]]*
 |-colorinterp{_bn} {red|green|blue|alpha|gray|undefined}]
 |-colorinterp {red|green|blue|alpha|gray|undefined},...]
 [-mo "META-TAG=VALUE"]* [-q] [-sds]
 [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-stats] [-norat]
 [-oo NAME=VALUE]*
 src_dataset dst_dataset
```

Comment: Probably GDAL does not understand that this `cache=PreferNetwork&crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&format=GeoTIFF&identifier=1&url=http://map.sitr.regione.sicilia.it/orbs/services/raster/Slope2x2_ata0708/MapServer/WCSServer` should be the input.  What and how did you try for making such command to appear?